# jQuery: Change background color of div on mousemove with colors from selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set about four colors, and use them for the background color of a div. There should be a smooth transition from one color to the next while moving the cursor.

My idea looks like that:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  let path = ["blue", "orange", "red", "green"]


  if ($pageX <= $pageY) {
    //???
  }

  $("div").css('background-color', path);

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #e57266;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="color-area"></div>
```

But every try failed. I would be soooo thankful for help! :)

Comment: within the `#color-area` div or the entire `document`? Would dividing the `#color-area` into path colours length vertically work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

A small modification to [@sergey's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64904960/jquery-change-background-color-of-div-on-mousemove-with-colors-from-selection/64905642#64905642) answer

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  let path = ["blue", "orange", "red", "green"]
  $("div").css('background-color', path[Math.floor(Math.random() * path.length)]);

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #e57266;
  transition: background 1s;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="color-area"></div>
```

You can change the transition if you want it faster

#### Edit

[@sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64904960/jquery-change-background-color-of-div-on-mousemove-with-colors-from-selection/64905642#64905642) managed to answer a few minutes before me!

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest such a solution. Add `transition: .1s` for `div` tag to smoothly change the color.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  let path = ["blue", "orange", "red", "green"]
  $("div").css('background-color', path[Math.floor(Math.random() * path.length)]);

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #e57266;
  
  transition: .1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="color-area"></div>
```